# Wordpress move post to trash if current post is not in API

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a PHP function that uses an API request. I then create a custom post type and store the values inside the Title, content and meta fields.

There is a unique identifier key called "requisitionId". I store this in a meta field.

The import works as expected. The problem I'm having is moving previously imported posts to trash if these are not in the incoming API.

I'm trying to do this by trying to check if the existing post's "requisitionId" exists in the incoming API. If not move this existing post to trash. I'm using the in_array() function to check this.

As it is right now, nothing is moving to trash.

The idea is to run a cron to keep the posts up to date with the API. That is why I need to move the existing posts to trash if they are not currently inline / up tp date with the API results.

What am I doing wrong and how can I improve the code?

```
foreach ( $jobs as $job ) {
    $jobs_count++;
    $job_role = ( $job['internalOnly'] == false ) ? 'External' : 'Internal'; 
    $job_title = $job['title'];
    $job_apply_link = $job['applyLink'];
    $job_department = $job['category'];
    $job_city = $job['locationCity'];
    $job_update_uf = $job['lastUpdatedDate'];
    $job_update = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', substr($job_update_uf, 0, 10));
    $job_requisition_id = $job['requisitionId'];
    $job_description_raw = $job['description'];
    $job_description = preg_replace('/ style=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/','',$job_description_raw);
    $job_post_title = $job_title;
    $job_slug = sanitize_title( $job['title'] . '-' . $job_city . '-' . $job_requisition_id );
    $job_post_category = sanitize_title( $job_department );

    $existing_job = get_page_by_path( $job_slug, 'OBJECT', $post_type = 'jobs' );

    $existing_job_id = $existing_job->ID;
    $existing_job_timestamp = $existing_job->post_date;

    $existing_job_requisition_id = get_post_meta( $existing_job_id, 'job-requisition-id', true );

    $job_ids_array = [];

    $job_ids_array[] = $job_requisition_id;

    //CREATE JOB
    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $job_post_title,
        'post_name' => $job_slug,
        'post_content' => $job_description,
        'post_date' => $job_update,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'jobs',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'job-requisition-id',
                'value'   => $job_requisition_id,
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        ),
    );

    if ( $job_role == 'External' ) {
        if ( $existing_job == null ) {
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-apply-link', $job_apply_link );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-published', $job_update );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-requisition-id', $job_requisition_id );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-role', $job_role );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_region, 'jobs-region' );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_city, 'jobs-city' );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_department, 'jobs-department' );

            $success_msg = $job_region . ' jobs imported. Please reload the page.'; 

        } else if ( ( $job_update > $existing_job_timestamp ) && ( $existing_job_requisition_id == $job_requisition_id ) ) {
            $update_jobs_args = array(
                'ID' => $existing_job_id,
                'post_title' => $job_post_title,
                'post_name' => $job_slug,
                'post_content' => $job_description,
                'post_date' => $job_update,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'jobs',
            );
            wp_update_post( $update_jobs_args );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-apply-link', $job_apply_link );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-requisition-id', $job_requisition_id );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-role', $job_role );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_region, 'jobs-region' );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_city, 'jobs-city' );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_department, 'jobs-department' );
            
            $success_msg = $job_region . ' Jobs updated. Please reload the page.';
                    
        } else if ( !in_array( $existing_job_requisition_id, $job_ids_array ) ) {
            // MOVE TO TRASH IF JOBS NO LONGER EXIST ON API
            $jobs_trash_args = array(
                'ID' => $existing_job_id,
                'post_status' => 'trash',
                'post_type' => 'jobs',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'job-requisition-id',
                        'value'   => $job_requisition_id,
                        'compare' => '=',
                    ),
                ),
            );
            wp_update_post( $jobs_trash_args );

            // IMPORT JOBS THAT DOES NOT EXIST
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-apply-link', $job_apply_link );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-published', $job_update );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-requisition-id', $job_requisition_id );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'job-role', $job_role );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_region, 'jobs-region' );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_city, 'jobs-city' );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $job_department, 'jobs-department' );

            $success_msg = 'Some new jobs were imported and some moved to trash.';
        }
    } else {
        $success_msg = 'There were no jobs to import. ' . $job_region . ' jobs are up to date.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified your check for whether this post should be moved to trash, actually yields true? And if so, have you checked the return value of the wp_update_post call?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here, but I have checked and I have an existing post that us supposed to move to trash (it's not).

Comment: I am simply asking, what you did so far to try and debug this. _"I have checked and I have an existing post that us supposed to move to trash"_ - and by that you mean, you have _manually_ checked what data your database contains? Okay, but that alone would not mean that the _code_ you wrote to check whether the post should be moved, is correct. So I am asking you, if you have verified *that* - for example via a debug output placed into that if block.

Comment: And if you did, and you can say for sure that `wp_update_post` was actually called - well then look at what it returned; that is supposed to give you feedback about whether the operation succeeded, or not.

Comment: I've verified by using `var_dump()` to check if the existing post requisitionId is in the API.
I've also checked the `wp_update_post ` and it was correctly called. Hope this helps?

Comment: I don't think trying to put a `meta_query` in there makes any sense. That is for _selecting_ posts, based on meta data criteria. The documentation says this takes the same parameters as https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ - so if you want to update meta fields of the post, you need to do that using `meta_input`

Comment: That makes sense. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks

Comment: It's not solving the problem though.

Comment: _"I've also checked the wp_update_post  and it was correctly called."_ - just to be clear, we are talking about checking the _return value_ of that function call, yes?

Comment: Hi @CBroe Sorry, I've failed to mention that the import is working great. The idea is to run a cron to keep the posts up to date with the API. That is why I need to move the existing posts to trash if they are not currently inline / up tp date with the API results. I've updated my question to include this.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, that you need to do a bit of debugging to figure out where the problem lies. If you can't run this in a browser so that you'd get to see debug outputs on screen - then write them to a file instead, and check the content of it afterwards. Or maybe test in a "stand-alone" script (some code you hack into a template or whatever) first, that the way you are currently attempting to move the post, works in general.

Comment: Okay I think I've found the problem. I will post my answer should I get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

The problem was that I was checking the incoming API IDs against itself. Instead of checking the existing post IDs against the incoming API IDs.

I'm also now permanently deleting all the posts before importing the new ones.

Here is the updated code:

```
    $jobs = $response['requisitions'];
$region = $_POST['region'];
$jobs_count = 0;
$success_msg = '';

$job_args = [
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'jobs-region',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $region,
        ]
    ]
];
$jobs_list = get_posts($job_args);
$jobs_deleted = count($jobs_list);

if ($jobs == null) {
    $success_msg = 'There are no open jobs for '.$job_region;
} else {
    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
        $job_role = ($job['internalOnly'] == false) ? 'External' : 'Internal'; 
        $job_title = $job['title'];
        $job_apply_link = $job['applyLink'];
        $job_department = $job['category'];
        $job_city = $job['locationCity'];
        $job_update_uf = $job['lastUpdatedDate'];
        $job_update = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', substr($job_update_uf, 0, 10));
        $job_requisition_id = $job['requisitionId'];
        $job_description_raw = $job['description'];
        $job_description = preg_replace('/ style=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/','',$job_description_raw);
        $job_post_title = $job_title;
        $job_slug = sanitize_title($job['title'].'-'.$job_city.'-'.$job_requisition_id);
        $job_post_category = sanitize_title($job_department);

        $existing_job = get_page_by_path($job_slug, 'OBJECT', 'jobs');

        $existing_job_id = $existing_job->ID;
        $existing_job_timestamp = $existing_job->post_date;

        $existing_job_requisition_id = get_post_meta($existing_job_id, 'job-requisition-id', true);

        $job_ids_array = [];

        $job_ids_array[] = $job_requisition_id;

        //CREATE JOB
        $args = [
            'post_title' => $job_post_title,
            'post_name' => $job_slug,
            'post_content' => $job_description,
            'post_date' => $job_update,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'jobs',
            'meta_input' => [
                'job-apply-link'   => $job_apply_link,
                'job-published'   => $job_update,
                'job-role'   => $job_role,
                'job-requisition-id'   => $job_requisition_id,
            ],
        ];

        if ($job_role == 'External') {
            $jobs_count++;
            if (empty($jobs_list)) {
                $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_region, 'jobs-region');
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_city, 'jobs-city');
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_department, 'jobs-department');
    
                $success_msg = $jobs_count.' '.$job_region.' jobs imported. Please reload the page.'; 
    
            } else if (!empty($jobs_list)) {
                
                foreach ($jobs_list as $item) {
                    wp_delete_post($item->ID, true);
                }
    
                $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
    
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_region, 'jobs-region');
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_city, 'jobs-city');
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_department, 'jobs-department');
    
                $success_msg = $jobs_deleted;
                $success_msg .= ' '.$job_region.' jobs deleted and ';
                $success_msg .= $jobs_count.' '.'imported. Please reload the page.';
    
            } else if (
                ($job_update > $existing_job_timestamp) &&
                ($existing_job_requisition_id == $job_requisition_id)) {
                $update_jobs_args = [
                    'ID' => $existing_job_id,
                    'post_title' => $job_post_title,
                    'post_name' => $job_slug,
                    'post_content' => $job_description,
                    'post_date' => $job_update,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'jobs',
                ];
                wp_update_post($update_jobs_args);
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'job-apply-link', $job_apply_link);
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'job-requisition-id', $job_requisition_id);
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'job-role', $job_role);
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_region, 'jobs-region');
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_city, 'jobs-city');
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $job_department, 'jobs-department');
                
                $success_msg = $job_region;
                $success_msg .= ' Jobs updated. Please reload the page.';
                        
            }
        } else {
            $success_msg = 'There were no jobs to import. '.$job_region.' jobs are up to date.';
        }
    }
}

echo  $success_msg;
```